# Firesharp OnAsync callback

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am listening to a node in Firebase, however the wrong event is fired when an action takes place. For example when updating a node in Firebase the removed (and changed) event is fired. Why is the removed event fired?

```
       await client.OnAsync("/groups",
                added: (s, args, d) =>
                {
                    string ss = "";
                },
                changed: (s, args, d) =>
                {
                    string ss = "";
                },
                removed: (s, args, d) =>
                {
                    string ss = "";
                });
```

Also is there an easy why to deserialize the data into an object?

Comment: Did you already figure out an easy way to deserialize? I am having the same issues right now, it seems like all (well, the most valuable things) I receive is a path to the added/changed section.